# How to list files after connecting to connect directory secure plus...I would like to list out all the file name

Tags: linux, shell-script

How to list files after connecting to Connect:Direct secure plus...I would like to list out all the file name .I'm connecting Linux to  mainframe via connect directory secure Plus.I would like to list out files name after connecting. Looks like ls command not working. Anyone knows any solution how to list out files.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you're referring to! Could you clarify: What does "connecting to connect directory secure" mean? And "plus" what? If this involves some software that we might not be familiar with, it would be good to link to it.

Comment: Connect direct secure plus is tool like SFTP,FTP...etc

Comment: "is tool like" will not enable us to help you! We need to know what *exactly* it is. Without a link to the tool's documentation this question is basically inanswerable. Also, what you listed are *protocols*, not tools.

Comment: Sorry yes its a protocol.

Comment: Just I wanted to list out filename after connecting via Connect:Direct secure plus protocol.

Comment: Ok, I vote to close this question as in need of details, as we have no information about that protocol, or how you use it, and you refuse to link to documentation.

Comment: I also didn't know how to use it. First time I'm going to use.I have no code to send you.

Comment: you're doing *something* to connect. Your software has some website, some documenation. We cannot look into your brain, we see only what you write in your question. What you're currently writing is "I use a tool that you haven't heard of, doing something I don't tell you, but that I describe as connecting, and expect `ls` to give me a directory listing. It doesn't."   I hope you understand that at the very least telling us exactly *how* that "connecting" is done, and where we can learn more about the software you're referring, is the **least** you need to do to enable anyone to help you.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: You’ve been told that we don’t know what you’re talking about, and that we need more information.  Are you talking about [this](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/connect-direct/6.0.0?topic=overview-what-is-connectdirect) / [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect:Direct)?  If so, *say so.*  But also, you say you have no idea how to use it.  Well, pardon me for being blunt, but use some common sense.  Are you at work?  If so, ask your boss, your IT support people, or a co-worker.  Did you buy it yourself?  Did it come with documentation?  Etc…

Answer (score 2):

Connect:Direct software is software that costs many thousands of $$$, then you have to pay many thousands of $$$ to get support. The op should be asking IBM.

However, the Connect:Direct software, with or without Secure Plus, does not allow directory listings. If you wish to get a list, the remote server will have to generate a listing to a file and allow you to pull that. This is for reasons of security.

And a bit of added info... C:D is mainly used in the financial industry to transfer files securely with non-repudiation. Where files are generated or stored may involve multiple institutions. They are never going to allow listings. Do you really want one bank to see what may be getting transferred to other banks?